# Auth0-lock-Error: An error occurred when fetching client data for Lock: https://cdn

Tags: node.js, auth0-lock

I'm using Auth0-lock to create an authentication dialog.I want to create an auth-lock object in a NodeJS file.When I used :

```
const {Auth0Lock} = require('auth0-lock');

var lock = new Auth0Lock(  MyClientId,  MyDomain); 
lock.show();
```

in my NodeJS file, I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\....\node_modules\auth0-lock\lib\utils\url_utils.js:6
var parser = global.document.createElement('a');
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
```

I defined a virtual dom element for it, using jsdom as follow:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body.....</body></html>');  

global.window = dom.window;  
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.location = dom.window.document.location;
```

By this, the above error was fixed, but I got another error without showing me the auth0-lock authentication dialog.It is:

```
Error: An error occurred when fetching client data for Lock: https://cdn.auth0.com/client/[MyClientId].js
```

Searches showed me this error indicates that Lock could not connect to the Auth0 CDN to fetch client. But when I uses auth0 cdn link and create auth-lock dialog in a html file using script as follow:

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.23.1/lock.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var lock = new Auth0Lock( MyClientId, MyDomain); 
    lock.show();
</script>
```

it worked with the exact same "MyClientId" and showed me the dialog.

Would you pleaes help me to fix this problem and display the dialog in my NodeJS file?

Thanks